# Parse can't retrieve CurrentUser's array objects

Tags: swift, parse-server

My PFUser Class has an array column as "liked"

I had tried to retrieve array like this

```
 let user = PFUser.current()
if let userLiked : NSArray = user?["liked"] as? NSArray{

            print(userLiked)


        }
```

But results is always "()" which has empty..

I don't know why it always return "empty strings"

Other user's column is well working like username or email..

```
 print(user?["displayname"] as! String)
```

Comment: Your array contains list of parse objects or it is just list of strings?

Comment: It just list of strings and I solved this problem. It's my fault thanks for reply